# Whats the point of the Ruby On Rails asset pipeline fingerprint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, nginx

This may seem extremely obvious to some but i'm having a hard time understanding the point behind compiling rails assets with a digest fingerprint. Surely the Last Modified header is all that is needed to bust the cache.

ran into a problem recently where I was deploying to 2 servers and I was compiling assets on the server. Requests were balanced between the 2 servers and Nginx was serving the assets. I noticed that the last modified timestamps where slightly different probably due to the compilation happening on different servers. So when the request came in from the user, the browser never cached the asset as every request was serving the `application-0fo45k46oi574634....js`, which was the same filename but had a different Last Modified time so it only ever responded with a 200 and never a 304. I can compile locally to get around the difference in Last Modified time but I am still wondering what the point of the fingerprint if compiling a new file is all that is need to bust the cache.

Im sure there is a good explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of fingerprinting is to provide reliable cache invalidation only when the file contents change, and not because of timestamps that change too often or because of caching policies that don't cache when the URL contains a querystring.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

Edit:  I'm well out of my area of expertise at this point, but I think that this may be happening because of a philosophical difference in caching strategy. With etag & last-modified, the server has to perform If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests, which can take server resources. In this case, there's no need for fingerprinting because as you said, last-modified is enough to bust cache.

But, another strategy is to remove etag & last-modified, and use expires + fingerprinting. In this case, the server won't need to perform if-* requests, and the cache is invalidated when the filename changes (or it expires, whichever comes first). So based on my reading, it seems like it's necessary only with the expires + fingerprinting caching strategy. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27694/last-modified-etags-to-include-or-not

Comment: Thanks, I have read that article and understand what its saying about cache busting with query strings but the part about "Too much cache invalidation" isn't valid. There is no point creating a new MD5 digest of the contents when the last modified is all that is needed to bust the cache.

Comment: The same file with the same content and MD5 digest which is on 2 separate servers but with slightly different modified times (because compilation happened on the servers) will keep responding with 200 and should respond with 304 because its the same file but as far as the browser is concerned it isn't because of the last modified time, so essentially we can ditch the MD5 digest, as browser only seem to look at last modified.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying.  I'm well out of my area of expertise at this point, but I think that this may be happening because of a philosophical difference in caching strategy.  With etag & last-modified, the server has to perform If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests, which can take server resources.  In this case, there's no need for fingerprinting because as you said, last-modified is enough to bust cache.

Comment: But, another strategy is to remove etag & last-modified, and use expires + fingerprinting.  In this case, the server won't need to perform if-* requests, and the cache is invalidated when the filename changes.  So based on my reading, it seems like it's necessary only with the expires + fingerprinting caching strategy.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27694/last-modified-etags-to-include-or-not

Comment: Thank you, perfect. Just the answer I was hoping to get. Perhaps you can update your original answer and i'll accept it? Im kind of surprise their isn't more information around this in the docs, perhaps there is and I just haven't found it??

Comment: I'm also surprised, it does seem like you've encountered a problem that's likely to be common.